# Error Dialog pops up during Unistallation

Tags: install4j, startmenu

When the uninstaller is executed with an user that has no admin permissions, the Windows UAC pops up and asks for login information of an admin user. If you enter the login information and go on with the unistallation, almost at the end an error Dialog Pops up that says the path "C:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\" doesn't exist. We checked before uninstallation and the path exists. If you execute the uninstaller directly from the admin account the Error Dialog doesn't show up. Also if we do an "update" installation, which first executes the unistaller then executes the installer, the error dialog doesn't show up either.
We are using Install4j 8.0.4.

Comment: You could execute the uninstaller from the command line with the argument `-Dinstall4j.log=<path to writable log file>` to get more information on what the uninstaller is doing and when it trying to access the mentioned path.

Comment: ok we are no longer able to reproduce this issue. It seems like the installation got corrupted by one of our developers.